# how to select text in several pre classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the following html structure and i want to select the text inside the underlying pre:

```
<span>[Select text 1]</span>
<pre class="selectme">
Text 1 goes shere 
</pre>

<span>[Select text 2]</span>
<pre class="selectme">
Text 2 goes here
</pre>
```

My javascript:

```
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){

var doc = document;
var element = this[0];
console.log(this, element);
  if (doc.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();        
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    }
};

$(function() {
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('.selectme').selectText();

  });
});
```

What happens now: if i click on the second span, the first code is selected. It should be the second
How can i achieve this without working with ID to the pre's?

http://jsfiddle.net/nuet/JAq2e/99/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.next()` to get the next element.

```
$('span').click(function() {
   $(this).next().selectText();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct your extension function because

```
var element = this[0];
```

is not the element on which you clicked.

You have to use:

```
var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
```

Like described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Event/target): A reference to the object that dispatched the event

A different solution is to pass the element in the click event:

```
        jQuery.fn.selectText = function(element){
            if (document.body.createTextRange) {
                var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(element);
                range.select();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                var selection = window.getSelection();
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNodeContents(element);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            }
        };

        $(function () {
            $('span').click(function() {
                $('.selectme').selectText(this);
            });
        });
```

The simple fix is:

```js
jQuery.fn.selectText = function(){
  // Support IE6-8
  var element = event.target || event.srcElement;
  if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var range = document.body.createTextRange();
    range.moveToElementText(element);
    range.select();
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(element);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
  }
};

$(function () {
  $('span').click(function() {
    $('.selectme').selectText();

  });
});
```

```css
span {

            cursor: pointer;

        }
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<span>[Select text 1]</span>
<pre class="selectme">
Text 1 goes shere
</pre>

<span>[Select text 2]</span>
<pre class="selectme">
Text 2 goes here
</pre>
```

Remember that any extension function must return a value to preserve the chaining, so consider to return for instance $(this).